# Problem with resizing (FormBorderStyle = None)

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I got a problem. When I set FormBorderStyle to None to make the form stripped down, it loses its expandability. I need to make it so that I can drag the edge of the form and it expands. That is, return the ability to resizing. How I can make it?

I tried to google it but found solutions for C# and I need to do it in C++

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates? Did this code help you?

Answer (score 0):

Redrawing WinForm can meet your needs.

You need to set FormBorderStyle to None then use following code.

```
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
              this->DoubleBuffered = true;
                    this->SetStyle(
                        System::Windows::Forms::ControlStyles::ResizeRedraw,
                        true);
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }
            int cGrip = 16;  // Grip size
            int cCaption = 32;
           protected:
            virtual void WndProc(System::Windows::Forms::Message %
                                 m) override {
              if (m.Msg == 0x84) {  // Trap WM_NCHITTEST
                Point pos = Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
                pos = this->PointToClient(pos);
                if (pos.Y < cCaption) {
                  m.Result = (IntPtr)2;  // HTCAPTION
                  return;
                }
                if (pos.X >= this->ClientSize.Width - cGrip &&
                    pos.Y >= this->ClientSize.Height - cGrip) {
                  m.Result = (IntPtr)17;  // HTBOTTOMRIGHT
                  return;
                }
if (pos.X <= this->ClientSize.Width - cGrip &&
                        pos.Y >= this->ClientSize.Height - cGrip) {
                      m.Result = (IntPtr)16;  
                      return;
                    }
                    if (pos.X <= this->ClientSize.Width - cGrip &&
                        pos.Y <= this->ClientSize.Height - cGrip) {
                      m.Result = (IntPtr)13;
                      return;

                    }
                 
                    if (pos.X >= this->ClientSize.Width - cGrip &&
                        pos.Y <= this->ClientSize.Height - cGrip) {
                      m.Result = (IntPtr)14;
                      return;
                    }
              }
              __super::WndProc(m);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I want. I just tried this code, it works, but only when I hover in the lower right corner, and I need to be able to stretch the application beyond any edge

Comment: @el1an hi, I updated my answer, you could try it.